# Как реализовать растения в игре типа Растения против Зомби? Юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Я хочу **попытаться** сделать игру по типу Растения против Зомби. Но не понимаю, как лучше и правильнее всего реализовать растения. В оригинальной игре их порядка 50 с лишним штук.
Каким образом лучше это реализовать?

Думаю, можно сделать **общий класс Plant**, в котором создать переменные для названия растения, его урона, здоровья, спрайта и т.д., а потом для каждого объекта создавать экземпляр класса, указывая для каждого растения свои переменные? Но что сделать потом? Я создам префаб растения и какой скрипт в таком случае мне на него вешать?

Или можно для каждого вида растения **прописать свой скрипт**, со своими переменными. Каждому растению прописать свое поведение (подсолнух - дает солнце, другие растения - стреляют, мину - взрываются, когда наступает зомби), а потом просто вешать скрипт, например, подсолнуха на префаб подсолнуха... Но в таком случае мне придется создавать много скриптов: **по 1 для каждого растения**. Мне кажется это неправильно.

Или можно... *сделать еще как-то.*

Comment: `Может сделать общий класс Plant, в котором создать переменные для названия растения, его урона, здоровья, спрайта и т.д., а потом для каждого объекта **создавать экземпляр класса, указывая для каждого растения свои переменные?` - Двигаетесь в правильном направлении.

Comment: Для даной задачи я бы советовал еще присмотреться к паттерну программирования "фабрика". Он именно для таких ситуаций и существует.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам придётся написать больше одного класса, но не для каждого растения.

Скрипт `GameUnit` просто содержит поле с префабом скина и ссылкой на скрипт `Skin`, объекта который он создаст из префаба, поле номера линии, количеством жизней, максимальных жизней, и функций получения урона и функцией смерти.

Ответственность класса `Plant` (наследуется от `GameUnit`) проста: цена, функция построения и поле номера клетки.

`Skin` с функциями проиграть rise, idle, walk, attack, dead настроенные под скин и для растений и для зомбаков.

`PlantBehaviour` просто находит класс `Plant` и хранит на него ссылку, для получения ссылки к скину и тайлу(линия и клетка).

`AttackBehaviour` умеющий палить врагов на своей линии что заставляет стрелять наследуется от `PlantBehaviour`.
Растения у которых какие-то необыные атаки (например атакуют врагов на всех линиях или соседних) имеют свой скрипт наследуемый от `AttackBehaviour` и меняют фунции палева врага или спавна снаряда.

У добытчиков скрипт `HarvestBehaviour`, наследуемое всё от тогоже `PlantBehaviour`.

У мин свой скрипт, а стенкам поведение вовсе не нужно.

`Zombie` тоже наследуются от `GameUnit`. Реализует атаку другого `GameUnit`.

У зомбаков свои скрипты передвижения как поведения растений и дополнительных фич типа щита и т.д.

У снарядов тоже могут быть разные скрипты.

Что-то примерно так.

Comment: Спасибо за подробные объяснения!

Comment: Подробный? Весьма поверхносный...

Comment: Мне же не нужно, чтобы вы прописали все методы, мне просто нужна была как раз иерархия и функциональность классов))) Но если хотите, то пусть будет поверхностный, главное, что понятный 

Comment: Правильно я понимаю: Skin висит на всех префабах раст. и зомби и для каждого я указываю свою анимацию walk, idle, rise...; GameUnit и Plant ни на чем не висят (или на отдельном объекте, типа GameLogic). А все Behaviour висят на соответствующих растениях? То есть бихейвиор мины на мине, простого стрелка на нем же и т. д.? Правильно?

Comment: И еще вопрос о функциональности класса PlantBehaviour. В чем его смысл, если он просто хранит ссылку на класс Plant. Почему нельзя просто унаследовать классы AttackBehaviour, HarvestBehaviour и т.д. напрямую от Plant, или не унаследовать, а добавить во все эти классы ссылку на Plant? В чем необходимость класса PlantBehaviour?

Comment: Ради бога. Но он там не только хранит поле ссылка, а еще и его заполнение в awake, без дублирования этого кода. Плюс наверняка будет общий функцианал для всех поведений типа остановки поведения при смерти или еще что. И `Plant` не придется искать разные классы в некую нужду, а тупо обращаться к `PlantBehaviour` какой бы он ни был если он есть.